# ClassCastException in B4A project

Tags: java, android, vb4android

I'm getting this exception:

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

in code shown below:

```vb
Private Sub MembersFileChooser_Result (Success As Boolean, Dir As String, FileName As String)
    If Success = True Then
        Wait For (AddMembers.Invoke(Dir, FileName)) Complete (Result As Boolean)
        If Result Then
            ToastMessageShow("Members added", False)
        Else
            ToastMessageShow("Failed to add members", False)
        End If
    Else
        ToastMessageShow("No file selected :(", False)
    End If
End Sub
```

AddMembers:

```vb
Public Sub Invoke(Dir As String, FileName As String) As ResumableSub
# Code here finally returns either False or Result of File.CopyAsync(Dir, FileName, Members.MembersDir, Members.MembersFile)
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What type does `AddMembers.Invoke` return? It looks like you're assuming it's a boolean, but is it?

Comment: I've updated the question; can you have a look please?

Comment: I see, "vb4android" confusingly refers to the B4A programming language/toolset https://www.b4x.com/